# Exception in thread “main” java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to create a web application in NetBeans 8.2, for this I try to use Apache Tomcat 8.0.27 which is integrated into this version. Previously I worked with Tomcat and Netbeans without any problem but in one occasion it failed.

I tried to modify environment variables in addition to reinstalling NetBeans with all its components but it did not work. I looked for information in other questions but I didn't find anything useful, possibly some file is corrupted but if it were the case, I would like to know how to solve it with a simple and understandable explanation, in some forums I read about how to find corrupted files and solve some things but they are not so clear to me.

Specs:
- Windows
- Netbeans 8.2
- Tomcat 8.0.27
- JDK & JDR 1.8.0.191

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError:** java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1052)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:249)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader.loadClass(ResourceBundle.java:512)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2649)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1510)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1474)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1370)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782)
    at sun.security.provider.AuthPolicyFile$1.run(AuthPolicyFile.java:74)
    at sun.security.provider.AuthPolicyFile$1.run(AuthPolicyFile.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.provider.AuthPolicyFile.<clinit>(AuthPolicyFile.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.security.auth.Policy$2.run(Policy.java:236)
    at javax.security.auth.Policy$2.run(Policy.java:228)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Policy.getPolicyNoCheck(Policy.java:227)
    at javax.security.auth.Policy.getPolicy(Policy.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

**Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file**
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:940)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(URLClassPath.java:801)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:886)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:879)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:878)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1050)
    ... 44 more
```

I would expect Tomcat to deploy without any problem but instead it is simply not deployed, sending the error every time.

Update: I installed the same NetBeans but in other computer AND it worked. I copyied the files of Tomcat and NetBeans but the error still (So, theres no a problem related to corrupted .jars i think). The project that im using to test it's a basic HTML page... A default Java web project.

Answer (score 0):

This problem in most part of times is a Exception of corrupted jars.
Are you trying to connect to any database? If yes, try to remove `.jar` file from `lib` folder on `WebContent` and copy the file from your computer directory to your folder on IDE and try again. If no, try to do this procedure to all of `.jars` that you're using on your project and replace them all again.